Create PDF with DomPDF and Laravel 8
i'm trying to create a PDF with DomPDF 2.2, but the base64 image is not recognized, but when I return the HTML the image is showing. I pass all the base64 code pure in the HTML. How I implement this.
<img style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" width="100%" src="data:image/png;base64, ' . $base64 . '" />

And the way I create the PDF:
$pdf = app('dompdf.wrapper');

$context = stream_context_create([
    ssl' => [
        verify_peer' => false,
        verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ]);
$pdf->getDomPDF()->setHttpContext($context);
$pdf->getDomPDF()->set_option("isPhpEnabled", true);
$pdf->getDomPDF()->set_option("isHtml5ParserEnabled", true);
$pdf->getDomPDF()->set_option("isRemoteEnabled", true);
$pdf->getDomPDF()->set_option("isFontSubsettingEnabled", true);
$pdf->getDomPDF()->set_option("enable_html5_parser", true);

ob_start();
$pdf->loadHtml($paginaHTML);
ob_get_clean();

$pdf->setPaper('letter', ($orientacion == 1 ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'));
$pdf->save(public_path('img/' . $pdfName));

Any idea what I did wrong

Your implementation is either incomplete, or wrong. There's a PHP variable called $base64, but nowhere do I see anything like <?php ..... ?>.

No, I am using Laravel and this code is on Var in a method, but when I print the PDF in my local it works and in my server does not find the image

Maybe not what you're looking for, but might be helpful.
place the image you need in a folder under app\public and then in the filesystems.php config file, create a symbolic link as shown below.
I used app/public/logos as an example below.
'links' => [
    public_path('logos') => storage_path('app/public/logos'),
],

Run the below command to create the symbolic link
php artisan storage:link

and then in the html view, you can point to the image using the below method through the app URL and directory you configured above.
<img src="{{ config('app.url') . '/logos/logo_no_bg_gray.png' }}" width="300px" alt="Logo">

Note: Make sure the APP_URL is configured properly when you move the application to your production server.

Thank u, but I changed the way I create my PDF. Instead of inserting a Base64 image, I'm now using a physical PNG image. It's weird because it used to work with Laravel 5, PHP 7, and DOMPDF 0.8, but now, with Laravel 8, PHP 8, and DOMPDF 2.2, it doesn’t work with Base64
